# Should I use useRef for storing one-time initialised data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

using react's ref today can be a little confusing.
back to the days of class components, it was very clear in the docs.

we should use refs mostly for **DOM elements** :

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

But today we have hooks together with functional components.
and we are using `useRef` hook.

also, this brings to us new patterns. using ref to contain **callbacks**, or any **data** we want to preserve (kind of state) but without the need to rerender.
its a powerful API and also shows up in the docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

so now ref can be used for:

1. store mutable data
2. kind of memoization

but these docs contradict each other. and causing many mistakes, and conflicts in development teams.

the doc says 2 different things and its a problem.

so, what is the "right" thing to do in a scenario like that?

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
   const [myMap1, _] = useState(new Map());    // 1.
   const myMap2 = useMemo(()=> new Map(), []); // 2.
   const myMap3 = useRef(new Map());           // 3.

   ...
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`useMemo` is a *declarative* [performance optimization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) technique.

Declarative, as it relies on state or props dependencies from the surrounding scope belonging to a particular render and automatically (re)creates the memoized value. We don't have to tell `useMemo` to do that.

`useRef` is a *mutable* storage box for any values, e.g. value updates independent from current render scope.

`useRef` does not have any dependencies, so no value is automatically changed. You have to do that manually by writing `ref.current = ...` (DOM nodes are an exception).
That is why you could see `useRef` as an escape hatch into the *imperative* world.

Now, we could try to mix their [usage interchangeably](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17962) for storage, like:

```
// instead of 
const val = useMemo(() => 42, [myDep]); // 42 stands for some complex calculation
// do this
const ref = useRef();
ref.current = 42 // assign 42 imperatively to ref somewhere in render
```

Or even [replace](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1099842565631819776?s=20) `useRef` by `useState`:

```
const [ref] = useState({current:null});
ref.current = "hello";
```

Disadvantage: we are back in old jQuery age :-). Operations have to be set imperatively, meaning more manual work and possible mistakes. Immutable value manipulations are also much more predictable than mutations (incl. other benefits). That is, why nearly everything in React is immutable.

Instead, it makes sense to stay declarative when possible (React idiomatic) and use the intended, optimized tools for their specific case:

- `useState` for immutable values in a declarative manner, triggers re-render
- `useMemo` for declarative memoization of costly values *derived from* state and props
- `useRef` for *mutable* values or DOM nodes - independent of render closure scope, no need for `deps`, doesn't trigger re-render, more manual imperative work

Comment: notice I have changed the first link to the docs. I had a mistake in the link before.
what do you say about the differences between docs. this is what matters.

Comment: Could you clarify in question, which exact statements you consider conflicting? With react class components, you have an implicit `this` context to store mutable instance values. With function components, that is not the case, so we need a Hook like `useRef` for this purpose. Regardless class or function: a ref remains a box, in which any values (DOM nodes, calculation etc.) can be stored and modified. So yes: ref got an additional use case for function components.

Comment: But what about memorization of immutable values that *aren't* derived from state and props and will never be changed, e.g., a library whose initialization is expensive?  Does it make a different if one uses state versus useRef here in terms of performance.  It doesn't seem very different to write useRef(createLibraryInterface()) and useState(createLibraryInterface()) other than one has to add .current and if you aren't every updating it there isn't any imperative issue.

Answer (score 1):

The hook useRef can be used to store any value, for example, you have an object or an array or a map which you don't want to reinitialize for every single rerender
you can use useRef hook.

```
 // this code will recreate the object in memory on each rerender
 const myObj = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}

 // here you have the same object in memory even after rerenders
 const refObj = useRef({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'})
```

similarly, useState hook can be used to store normal state variables.

useMemo is useful when some value depends on another variable in your code and you want to change the value only if the variable changes (useful when passing props as an object or passing a memoized object to the value prop passed to a context provider).